# Can't install android studio on linux mint 17.2

Tags: permissions, linux-mint, sh

I have downloaded android studio for linux , after unzipping the zip file I went to specif location which is `android-studion/bin` and open terminal there then i run `./studio.sh` command , when I run this command , it says permission denied . Also I tried to change the file permission by `sudo chmod -R o+w  android-studio` this command , but doesn't work .

Edit: studio.sh is a file under bin , which I need to execute in order to install

I am running Windows 8 and linux mint parallay . After downloading the the zip folder , I move that to another drive , which is both available in linux and windows . Is this causing any problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. cd into the android-studio folder.
2. Execute **chown -R your_username:your_username .** Including the dot. If you get permission denied, add sudo in the start.
3. Execute **chmod -R 755 .** again including the dot.
4. Finally, run Android Studio by typing **./bin/studio.sh**

Replace your_username from step 2 to Your Username.

This will make you the owner of all the files contained in the folder and give you execution rights.

Comment: I tried , but didn't work . 

Is there anything to do with dual installation ? I am running Windows 8 and linux mint parallay . After downloading the the zip folder , I move that to another drive , which is both available in linux and windows . Is this causing any problem ?

Comment: Therein lies the problem. For any linux executable to run, it must be on a Journaled File System e.g. ext4, ext3, etc. so that it can manage the execution rights. The shared file system is probably ntfs formatted. Copy/move the whole android-studio directory to your home directory and run the commands again.

Comment: It worked thanks  , is there any way to install software from other drive ?

Comment: You can do anything with Linux and an NTFS or FAT32 formatted drive except running an executable.